# Java is not recognized on my macs terminal

Tags: java, macos

I am trying to make a Minecraft Bukkit server for 1.8 and up but java doesn't work as a command in my mac's terminal. I *do* have the latest Java JDK but it does not work a command in my terminal... **please help**

Comment: create `Java_home` in your `.Bash` file. Google it !!

Comment: Set up the 'JAVA_home' system environment variable and the also add it to the 'PATH' variable. Google will tell you how to do that.

Comment: How do I do any of these things sorry I'm a complete computer noob (google isn't helping"

Answer (score 0):

Type in `java` by itself into Terminal, and comment the output. If you get this output:

```
    Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
blah blah blah....
```

Then java is installed, but your JAVA_home variable is not set up. 
This link will help you set it up: [Oracle JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/index.html)

Comment: (-bash: java: command not found) ...        is the output I receive without the parenthesis

Comment: why did you ask me to do something then not respond?

Comment: hello again. go to oracle and install java again.

Comment: I did and it tells me the same thing

Comment: This problem started happening after I typed this command:              #!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
exec java -Xmx2G -Xms2G -jar spigot.jar nogui